# Where does the value 1200 come from in this equation for a uniformly continuous function

Tags: calculus, continuity

This example came from the $\epsilon-\delta$ criterion section of my book:

$f(x)=x^{3}$ for $x$ in $[0,20].$
Then the function $f$ is uniformly continuous.  To see this, observe that for all $u$ and $v$ in $[0,20]$,

$|f(u)-f(v)|=|u^{2}+uv+v^{2}| |u-v|\leq{1200}|u-v|$

I see this example has used the difference of powers, but I can't seem to follow where 1200 is coming from...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The max $|u^2 + uv + v^2|$ can possibly be on the interval $[0,20]$ is when $u = v = 20$. Therefore $|f(u)-f(v)| \leq |20^2+20^2+20^2||u-v| = 1200|u-v|$.

Comment: Thank you, that is very clear!

Answer (score 1):

$u,v$ can be atmost $20$ so $20^2+20\times 20+20^2=1200$